# How to create an action item with sub-items programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, menuitem

### Background

Just want to see how to make action items in code without XML

### The problem

I've come to some case that I fail to see how I can create in code.

The case below is showing a normal action-item that has an icon, and when pressed, it shows a sub-menu of items to choose from. I want to create the same, but programmatically:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" android:title="More info" app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
      <group android:checkableBehavior="none" android:menuCategory="container">
        <item android:id="@+id/..." android:title="item 1"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/..." android:title="item 2"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/..." android:title="item 3"/>
      </group>
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

When using this, the result is:

[image]

And after clicking:

[image]

### What I've tried

I tried 2 solutions:

1. Create a subMenu (using [**addSubMenu**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#addSubMenu(java.lang.CharSequence))), and then setting an action-item properties to it.
2. Create a normal Action item (using [**add**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#add(java.lang.CharSequence))) and then adding sub-items to it.

The result for both of them failed in comparison to what

### The question

How can I make the exact same thing programmatically, without using XML resource for it.

Comment: Could you please share what you result you are getting?

Comment: @PankajKumar I already wrote: an action item that has an icon, that when you click on it shows a menu. I've updated the question with screenshots.